# How do I get Centos VM to re-read its increased Disk size WITHOUT a reboot

Tags: linux

I have a CentOS 5 VM and I've just increased the VM disk from 10G to 20G, but I cannot get fdisk to see the new disk size without a reboot.

I've tried `echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/rescan`, it seems to indicate it can see the new size, but when I go to fdisk to create a new partion it still sees the disk as 10G.

Any ideas?

Comment: Depending on your virtualisation platform and storage method, this may or may not be possible.  Details matter.

Comment: Which virtual disk type you've added: IDE or SCSI?

Comment: That first command worked for me...

Comment: echo 1 > /sys/class/block/sdX/device/rescan worked for me , notice the /class inclusion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to issue the rescan command to your SCSI bus.

In VMware the SCSI controller might be found in some unusual place. First find it:

```
find /sys -iname 'scan'
```

For me that returned

```
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/host0/scsi_host/host0/scan
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/host1/scsi_host/host1/scan
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/host2/scsi_host/host2/scan
```

Then just issue the rescan command

```
echo "- - -" >/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/host0/scsi_host/host0/scan
echo "- - -" >/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/host0/scsi_host/host1/scan
echo "- - -" >/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/host0/scsi_host/host2/scan
```

That *should* help. :)

Comment: `ls /sys/class/scsi_host` maybe faster.

Comment: 9 years later... just wanna mention this made my VM go down with "ext4-fs ERROR" notices, had to stop and restart the VM. It all worked out, but still, gonna comment here to warn people this might happen. Aaaand after the reboot, the increased disk size was picked up of course.

Answer (score 17):

I had to deal with a similar problem, on a SLES 11 server. 
The LVM was built with raw disks, running on VMWare ESXi

```
# pvcreate /dev/sdd; vgextend ....
```

After a while I needed to increase LVM size, but I didn't add a supplemental disk and then pvcreate + vgextend as I've done before, but I chose to increase the size of an existing disk (/dev/sdd in this case). After doing the increase in VMWare, I executed a

```
# rescan-scsi-bus.sh
```

But pvdisplay was still showing the 'old' disk size. It was necessary to do a

```
# echo 1 > /sys/block/sdd/device/rescan
```

for the kernel to learn the new disk size of /dev/sdd

Comment: `echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/rescan` worked for me on CentOS

Comment: -bash: /sys/module/scsi_mod/parameters/scan: Permission denied, username is root

Answer (score 16):

after first doing `echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/rescan`

`pvresize /dev/sda` did the trick for me

Answer (score 5):

To detect changes to existing disk:

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/block/sdX/device/rescan
```

To detect new disk:

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/scsi_device/X:X:X:X/device/block/device/rescan
```

To find X in the first situation you can use `fdisk -l`.

https://kerneltalks.com/disk-management/how-to-rescan-disk-in-linux-after-extending-vmware-disk/

Comment: `ls: cannot access '/sys/class/scsi_device/*/device/block/device/rescan': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3):

If the partition table is directly in use (e.g. you have mounted filesystem using a base partition) the kernel will continue to use the old partition table until this is no longer the case. Someone once told me that if you are using LVM you can get around this....

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** 
Centos 6 - not possible to update partition table of active disk online,
Centos 7 - it is possible to extend last partition with **growpart** or create new partition with fdisk and make it visible without reboot with **partprobe**. Probably same on ubuntu/debian. - At some point after 2.6 kernel started supporting online reread of partition table of active disk. Since question is for Centos 5 I would say no way.

If you are using partitions then you have to reboot to use new space. I didn't find a way to avoid this. If someone has let me know.

However, reboot should be done after you extend last partition on the disk or add new partition. Doesn't make sense to reboot before.

First thing you should notice after rescan is bigger disk size in fdisk and in lsblk. If you don't see it you have to play with these echo 1 and echo - - - commands.

After you see more space you can extend/add partition, then reboot, extend vg, extend lv and fs.

If you want to avoid reboot you have to assign raw sda/b/c disk to volume group without partitioning it to sda1/2/3. Then there is no need for reboot.

Partitioning was necessary some time ago when linux could not boot from LVM, but now it can.

If you do lsblk you will see partitions or lvms depending on if you are using partitions or lvm, you can have all parts if you don't use lvm or all lvms if you don't use partitions. Here is one example:

```
root@srv4 ~ $ lsblk
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                           8:0    0  7.3T  0 disk
├─sda1                        8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                        8:2    0  7.3T  0 part
  ├─vg_srv4-LogVol13 (dm-0) 253:0    0  7.1T  0 lvm  /
  ├─vg_srv4-LogVol05 (dm-1) 253:1    0  100G  0 lvm  /var/log
  ├─vg_srv4-LogVol04 (dm-2) 253:2    0   20G  0 lvm  /var
  ├─vg_srv4-LogVol01 (dm-5) 253:5    0   20G  0 lvm  /opt
  ├─vg_srv4-LogVol00 (dm-6) 253:6    0   20G  0 lvm  /home
  ├─vg_srv4-LogVol03 (dm-7) 253:7    0   20G  0 lvm  /usr
  └─vg_srv4-LogVol02 (dm-8) 253:8    0    8G  0 lvm  /tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS 7, I used `rescan-scsi-bus.sh -s` for this.

The `-s` switch specifically instructs `rescan-scsi-bus.sh` to scan for resized disks.

`rescan-scsi-bus.sh -s` can be found in the **sg3_utils** package.

```
[root@udplinux host0]# rescan-scsi-bus.sh -s
which: no multipath in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
Scanning SCSI subsystem for new devices
Searching for resized LUNs
RESIZED: Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: VMware   Model: Virtual disk     Rev: 2.0
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 06
0 new or changed device(s) found.
1 remapped or resized device(s) found.
        [0:0:0:0]
0 device(s) removed.
[root@udplinux host0]#
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this maybe a little late, but I'm running KVM on the host. To get the disk size change I had to trigger it on the host, not the guest.
In my case it was

- Use lvm to extend the volume space `lvextend -L+4G /dev/<volume group>/<volume>`
- Get the disk / block info `virsh qemu-monitor-command <vm name from virsh list> --hmp "info block"`
- Tell kvm of the changes `virsh qemu-monitor-command <vm name> --hmp "block_resize drive-virtio-disk2 <new size>"`

I had previously run commands like `echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host1/scan`  but nothing changed until I ran the the `virsh qemu-monitor-command -hmp` command

Answer (score -4):

You have to reboot, there's no way around that.

Comment: How about the force system to rescan?

Comment: I did have to reboot :-(

Comment: I had to reboot too.

Comment: This is completely untrue. I have done this multiple times without rebooting.

Comment: With CentOS7.5 running under VMware, I have tried all the suggestions above - all the echos to .../rescan and .../scan, and the new VMware disk size has not been recognized.  Obviously, it works for some folks in presumably different circumstances.

Comment: I have successfully done this without reboot before. However failing on one box. `echo 1 > /sys....rescan` works, `fdisk` sees new size, but after extending partition used by LVM `partprobe` can not inform kernel of the change, tells me to reboot. I don't know what's different this time.